# How to interpret the following sentence?

Tags: american-english

I have fridge with broken/not-working compressor which needs replacement. I called a technician and he gave me a quote.

Now the tricky part, I have a warranty/insurance and they asked me to fill out the form.

There is one question which needs a yes or no answer but I don't quite understand it.

---

> I affirm that no equipment replacement is required, nor am I recommending replacement of the system I have diagnosed. This is a parts/labor repair that will be completed timely by my company.

ANSWER : YES/NO?

---

How do I interpret the above question? We need to replace the compressor as suggested by technician.

The question is for technician and I am just helping out.

Comment: You're not replacing the refrigerator.

Comment: @HotLicks The technician is, however, replacing the compressor. Why the customer is being expected to fill in the technician's report form, however, I do not understand. The customer is claiming for the cost of a new compressor, for the technician's time to make the replacement, and the call-out fee. If the company makes a distinction between the equipment (entire refridgerator) and a component thereof they aren't making it clear.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is a little carelessly composed. It first uses *equipment* but then refers to *system*.

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/equipment)
> *equipment*
> the set of articles or physical resources serving to equip a person or thing: such as:
> the implements used in an operation or activity

In your statement, *equipment* refers to the fridge and not to the compressor, because the compressor clearly serves to equip the fridge to do its job.

Similarly, *system* refers to the fridge and not to the compressor:

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/system)
> *system*
> a regularly interacting or interdependent group of items forming a unified whole

The *system* is therefore the fridge (a group of components forming a cooling system), and not the compressor, which is merely one of the components.

*Nor am I …* means *I am not …*

The statement therefore may be read as:

*I affirm that no fridge replacement is required, and I am not recommending replacement of the fridge I have diagnosed. This is a parts/labor repair that will be completed timely by my company.*

As a true statement that the compressor should be replaced and that the fridge does not need replacing, it should be answered by “Yes”.

Answer (score -1):

The conjunction “nor” negates whatever follows. Therefore, by answering “yes” the technician affirms two things:

1. that no equipment replacement is required and
2. that he is not recommending replacement of the system he has diagnosed.

If he needs to replace any equipment (which I assume would include a compressor), then it seems that he should answer “no”.